# How to put bullets in rml/openoffice

Tags: python, odoo, openoffice-writer, rml

i want to add bullets in openoffice for each optional product in OpenERP

```
[[repeatIn(o.order_line,'line')]]
[[repeatIn(line.product_id.product_ids, 'optionals')]]
[[optionals.name]].......................[[optionals.list_price]] + IVA
```

the point is that the bullet is in every line (before optionals.name) but i dont know how to add it manually by rml. If i use the bullets of openoffice it adds numbers (1, 2, 3) and in a line before.

How can i add a bullet for every line? Its fine if its in openoffice or rml.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<bullet>` tag for print bullet symbol in rml report.

```
<bullet
    bulletColor = alphanumeric
    bulletFontName = alphanumeric
    bulletFontSize = alphanumeric
    bulletIndent = alphanumeric
    bulletOffsetY = alphanumeric >
....
....
....
</bullet>
```

Hope this will help you.